# Как в Apache 2 добавить обработчик событий на cgi-script?

Tags: apache, apache2, cgi, handlers

Есть два cgi-скрипта нужно, чтобы сначала выполнился один cgi-скрипт, а потом второй. Делать в первом переадресацию на страницу другого скрипта не нужно, по типу такого

```
print Status: 302
print Location: http://...../second_cgi
```

Нашел что для этого, возможно, может подойти handler.

И есть ли решение, когда скриптов больше чем два и они могут вызываться друг за другом по определённой последовательности